# Search a term in one cell on a specific website then return resulting URL

Tags: excel, vba, excel-web-query

So I have very little experience with web queries in VBA. Currently, I have a column of gecodes that require a satellite image of the location.

I want to use this website :http://google-maps.pro/satellite and search in the search bar, then return the resulting URL. Currently I have "http://google-maps.pro/satellite#" in one cell and concatenate it with the geocode, it does not work (although this works for other websites).

I am not sure if this is even a web query, as while learning I see that most web query scripts seem to focus on returning an html table, whereas I just want the URL. What exactly is it that I am looking for? Am I wasting time learning web querying with VBA?

EDIT: Solved, read URL wrong.

Comment: Could you please specify what are the geocodes you have and what is the expected result URL?

Comment: Actually I have realized that I am just stupid. The concatenate worked except I missed that there was a ",19" added to the end of every generated URL.